# Inserting a new relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm just looking through the docs:

```
$post = Post::find(1);

$comments = array(
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A new comment.')),
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A second comment.')),
);

$post->comments()->save($comments);
```

I've implemented something similar to the above on my site, my question is, I wish to also insert a new Post at the same time, is there a way to do this, instead of using find?

Also what happens if the insert of the post fails, can I prevent the comments from being inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Parent of the relationship must be saved prior to saving related models. Can't be done in 1 go. (btw `push` won't work for it either, in case you wonder).

```
$post = Post::create([ ... post data here ...]);
// or
$post = new Post;
$post->whatever = 'someValue';
$post->save();

// then
$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

Comment: I think you need to use `saveMany` instead of `save` here

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it this way:

```
$post = new Post();

$post->title = 'my title';

$post->save();

$comments = array(
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A new comment.')),
    new Comment(array('message' => 'A second comment.')),
);

$post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
```

this way you will create new post and save comments for it. I haven't tested what happens if something goes wrong but I assume comments won't be inserted because there won't be related post id.

Comment: No, it won't create relationship, nor will it save the comments. And btw you can't assign relations by just setting them like that.

Comment: Thanks, so what should I do? Test if postId is ok then proceed with inserting comments? –

Answer (score 0):

Why not first create a post then attach the related model something like this.

```
$post = new Post();
$post->save();
```

Then iterate through comments and assign the post_id attribute in comment table.

The id field of post model will be available if the post exists.

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->post_id = $post->id;
$comment->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, so what should I do? Test if postId is ok then proceed with inserting comments?

Comment: You can check that if $post->save(); is successful or not. Even, If somehow the post is not created $post->id will fail. As it will be only available if the post you created above exists.